# Angular js Facebook Login

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

I want to use Facebook Login on my project. When the Facebook button is clicked I call checkLoginState function bu I get an error. I put angular js script file and I used ng-app. How can I solve this problem?

**The error code is**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="text-center">{{userName}}</div>
<fb:login-button  data-auto-logout-link="true" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="$scope.checkLoginState();">Sign İn</fb:login-button>
```

**Script Code**

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '391188****',
        cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
        xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
        version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.5
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        $scope.statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
};                  

var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_EN/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    $scope.checkLoginState=function() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            $scope.statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }               
    $scope.statusChangeCallback=function(response) {
        if(accessToken){
            var accessToken=response.authResponse.accessToken;
        }               
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            $scope.send(accessToken);   
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') { 
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '';
        } else{
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = '';
        }
    }
    $scope.send = function(accessToken){
        $http({
            method  : 'POST',
            url  : 'https://example.com',
            data:{
                'smType':type,
                'smID':accessToken
            },
            headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} 
        }).success(function(data) {
            if (data.errors) {
                console.log("An error occurred");
            } else {
                    $scope.userName=data.name;
            }
        });
    };                      
}]);
```

Comment: Is `$scope` accessible in statusChangeCallback`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to call checkLoginState from your html, it has to be inside your controller and attached to $scope:

`$scope.checkLoginState=function(){...}`

Second of all, you can't use $scope in statusChangeCallback without passing it in. So either put statusChangeCallback inside your controller or pass in $scope as an argument.

Third of all, make sure you are injected $scope into your controller. 
`app.controller('ctrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){...}])`

Comment: Can you show me your new code? Also are you sure your template is attached to that controller? Do you have ng-route or did you use ng-controller?

Comment: No, don't put onlogin=$scope.checkLoginState(). Just onlogin="checkLoginState()" . the $scope is implied

Comment: Also remove the ; from onlogin. Just put onlogin="checkLoginState()" . If there is still no error, you have to debug the rest of the code inside the function. You can do this using Chrome developer tools and using break points. Do you mind voting me up for the help I have given you?

Comment: I edited as your said I get Uncaught ReferenceError: statusChangeCallback is not defined error.